# VB.NET Reference a Label's Text in DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, syntax

I'm attempting to reference the text from a label in a DetailsView in my CodeBehind, then pass it through a Stored Procedure.

My DetailsView is DetailsView1, and the two fields are lblDialID & lblCallbackID.  I've converted them to TemplateFields.  The data is populating properly, but when I'm attempting to grab the data and pass it, I'm not getting any results.

The Stored Procedure is not performing it's action, and a Response.Write on the variables does not produce any results so assumedly I'm just grabbing thin air :)

Any guidance here?

```
Protected Sub lnkCBtoPUB_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)    
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD")
Dim MyCommand As New SqlCommand
Dim sDialID As Label = CType(DetailsView1.FindControl("lblDialID"), Label)
Dim sCallbackID As Label = CType(DetailsView1.FindControl("lblCallbackID"), Label)

Conn.Open()
MyCommand.Connection = Conn
MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
MyCommand.CommandText = "spAlterAgentCallback"
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DialID", sDialID.Text)
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallbackID", sCallbackID.Text)

MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Conn.Close()
Conn.Dispose()
MyCommand.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Here is the Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAlterAgentCallback]
@DialID AS INT,
@CallBackID AS INT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE DIAL 
SET CBDATETIME = GETDATE(),
AgentID = '',
CRC = 'SCBR',
Notes = 'This Record Was Recently a Callback for Another Agent.'
WHERE DialID = @DialID

DELETE FROM CALLBACK WHERE CallBackID = @CallBackID
END
```

<>
Could this also be because I am passing a string, but the SP is taking it as an INT? This shouldn't pose a problem though?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in your AddWithValue, you need to access the Text Property of the Labels instead of passing the Label object into the proc and you should be okay.

So:

```
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DialID", sDialID.Text)
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallbackID", sCallbackID.Text)
```

If you weren't getting the controls, it would have thrown a NullReferenceException.

**EDIT:**

As for the SP you need to isolate where the issue is occurring.  Try running the SProc from SQL Management Studio giving the parameters that .NET would pass in and confirm the proc is running.  If it does work, I would debug your code to make sure the values make it into the parameters.  The Integer type shouldn't matter because .NET looks up the type later.  If you wanted to be safe, you could parse them into integer's before sending them to the Proc.

**EDIT2:**

You could try using Hidden Fields in this way:

(Somewhere in your detailsview)

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="_CtlDialIDHidden" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("DialID")%>' />
<asp:HiddenField ID="_CtlCallbackIDHidden" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("CallbackID")%>' />
```

And in your click event

```
If Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("_CtlDialIDHidden") Then
    MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DialID",  Request.Form.Item(Request.Form.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(Function(x As String) x.Contains("_CtlDialIDHidden"))))
End If
If Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("_CtlCallbackIDHidden") Then
    MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallbackID",  Request.Form.Item(Request.Form.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(Function(x As String) x.Contains("_CtlCallbackIDHidden"))))
End If
```

You may have to view source to see exactly what the name being passed back is instead of using the lambda expressions.

Comment: I made the appropriate changes, and I'm unable to produce the desired results.

Comment: The Stored Procedure is pretty straight forward.  I've added the Stored Procedure above.

Comment: The SP works fine in SQL, that was tested prior to writing the VB.  I'm still under the assumption that I'm simply not grabbing the values properly, not that you're wrong, but that's just my assumption.

Comment: @RogueSpear00 Is it possible that you are databinding the details view prior to this code executing (for example in Page Load)? In that case, the values may not be present when you go to look them up.  If this is on a form post, try creating hidden fields to hold your values and looking them up in the Request.Form object and passing those values into the SProc params.

Comment: the code executes AFTER the DetailsView is initiated. The way this form works is I have a GridView, the user selects a record and the DetailsView populates and shows, and in that DetailsView is the actual LinkButton that you see in the example.

Comment: @RogueSpear00  Your selectors for the Labels look correct.  If when you debug you see no values for the label.text property when you know it was there, you may be encountering a Page LifeCycle issue.  I'm not sure how the rest of your code looks but you could use the hidden fields to persist the data you're looking for.  More on page lifecycle here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events   With specific emphasis on the Control Events, PreRender and PreRenderComplete events. See my edit for what I mean with the hidden fields.

Comment: When I put in some breakpoints (Mind you I'm not super amazing at .NET or VS Studio) the code never hits the breakpoints.  Is this because it's in the DetailsView?  I'm somewhat at a loss here...

Comment: You put the breakpoints in the lnkCBtoPUB_Click method and the breakpoints don't fire?  Make sure the OnClick of the LinkButton is set.  Normally you could put a handles clause after the method like lnkCBtoPUB_Click(ByVal object As Sender, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkCBtoPUB_Click.Click, but because it is in a detailsview, you have to set the OnClick property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4098/discussion-between-oopeanutbutter-and-roguespear00)